# What unit would the answer be in?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, units

So I have used this formula: 
$$W= PV_1 \times \ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$$
and I have converted my values to cubic meters and pascals. So Work Done, $W$, what would be the unit for that answer? I already have my answer but I am not sure what unit to label it in. Joules? I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in joules.

The term $\ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}$ is unitless, because the units on the top and bottom of the fraction cancel. [Pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure), in pascals, is defined as Newtons per square meter. You've already put the volume into cubic meters, and the cancellation goes
$$\text{meters}^3 \times \frac{\text{Newtons}}{\text{meters}^2}=\text{Newtons} \times \text{meter}$$
which is the definition of a joule.

Answer (score 0):

$V_1/V_1$ units will get cancelled.
Substituting the dimensions of remaining units,

$$\frac{\text{length}^3\times \text{Force}}{\text{length}^2}=Force\times length$$

The formula for work too is $Force \times displacement~$. Since the unit of Work is Joules, The unit of $Force\times length$ will be Joules too